# Does anyone object to merging all the answers here to a canonical question?

Tags: discussion, canonical-questions

This 4x4 request for window management is a very nicely explained special case of a general problem. All the answers seem to fit the canonical question instead of the specific twist.

- [Open source 4-way split screen on macOS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/411187/open-source-4-way-split-screen-on-macos)

Any objections to merging all the answers over?

Comment: The questions and the number of answers that offer numerous solutions on both questions, look like a good candidate for a Canonical question merging... IMHO...

Comment: Did this take place? No objections from me.

Comment: Not until your kind reminder @stevec much obliged

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No objections were raised for a merge.

It is complete.